# Replace "," in a list with "."

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list which consists of numbers which use comma (,) instead of dot (.) as their decimal point. I would like to replace the commas, but only those commas which are followed by more than five digits, with a dot.

A little example:

```
{0, "", 0, 1, 3, 93345, 27, 763212, 3}
```

should be converted into:

```
{0, "", 0, 1, 3.93345`, 27.763212`, 3}
```

Comment: In the first list there is no information which komma is real NumberPoint and which only komma. So You have to a) deal with the komma while or before importing this list or b) specify somehow which positions consist of FractionalParts for example. Then We can talk about details.

Comment: Are you importing data into *Mathematica*? It might be better to just tweak the options of `Import[]` so that commas are interpreted as decimal points...

Comment: Can you improve your question title? It's not very specific at the moment.

Comment: Frink, I noticed that you have an "Unregistered" account with more reputation than this one.  I have submitted a merge request on your behalf; you should have the combined "reputation" from both accounts soon.

Comment: You are right Mr. Wizard. Thank you for merging :-)

Answer (score 11):

As already stated by others this is almost certainly an import problem and should be addressed at that level.  For example:

```
ImportString["12,345 678,910", "Table", "NumberPoint" -> ","]
```

> ```
> {{12.345, 678.91}}
> ```

See ["Table" format documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/Table.html) for more information.

Nevertheless the proposed replacement problem itself is mildly interesting.

Here is one method:

```
{0, "", 0, 1, 3, 93345, 27, 763212, 3} //.
 {a___, x_Integer, y_Integer, b___} /; y > 9999 :>
  {a, x + y/10`^IntegerLength[y], b}
```

> ```
> {0, "", 0, 1, 3.93345, 27.7632, 3}
> ```

This would be inefficient for long lists because `ReplaceRepeated` (short from `//.`) will rescan the entire expression after each individual replacement.  A better approach might be to something like this, the difference being that the replacement is only applied to the parts that haven't already matched:

```
f = # /. {a___, x_Integer, y_Integer, b___} /; y > 9999 :>
  {a, x + y/10`^IntegerLength[y], f@{b}} &;

f @ {0, "", 0, 1, 3, 93345, 27, 763212, 3} // Flatten
```

> ```
> {0, "", 0, 1, 3.93345, 27.7632, 3}
> ```

Another approach for better efficiency would be to section the list with `Partition` and apply the replacement to those section, then merge with `Flatten`.  A partition length of three is needed to avoid separating the parts of any number.

```
Replace[
  Partition[{0, "", 0, 1, 3, 93345, 27, 763212, 3}, 3, 3],
  {a___, x_Integer, y_Integer, b___} /; y > 9999 :>
   {a, x + y/10`^IntegerLength[y], b},
  {1}
] ~Flatten~ 1
```

> ```
> {0, "", 0, 1, 3.93345, 27.7632, 3}
> ```

In a different direction you could use string processing which is optimized for this kind of replacement, but other aspects of your expression can change during the conversion.

```
s = ToString[{0, "", 0, 1, 3, 93345, 27, 763212, 3}, InputForm]

StringReplace[s, 
  int : DigitCharacter .. ~~ ", " ~~ dec : Repeated[DigitCharacter, {5, ∞}] :>
    int ~~ "." ~~ dec
] // ToExpression
```

> ```
> {0, "", 0, 1, 3.93345, 27.7632, 3}
> ```

Comment: That's very nice, Mr.W. Would `list /. {a___, x_Integer, y_Integer, b___} /; y > 9999 :> {a, 
   x + y/10^IntegerLength[y], b}` be similar to your 'better approach'?

Comment: Since you are going for the omnibus, let´s not forget a `Sow`/`Reap` one :-)

Comment: @cormullion I don't think I understand; wouldn't that catch only the first case?  Using `y > 9999` however is a nice shortening of `IntegerLength[y] >= 5`; mind if I incorporate it?

Comment: @Yves I'll have to think about that.  An elegant method using those does not come to mind. (Not that what I wrote is elegant, but it would be nice to present `Sow`/`Reap` elegantly.)  Did you have something specific in mind?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Oh, yes, I didn't spot that - *fail*. Go ahead!

Comment: @cormullion Speaking of *fail* this keyboard keeps leaving out characters.  I either need a new one, or I need to fix my IBM Model M which stopped working reliably after 20 years of service.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard nothing pretty, just a `For` loop with some conditional `Sow`ing. You might go for `Sow` tags if you feel fancy, but I feel it would be overkill for a probable `Import`-related issue.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Time to move into the 21st century. Mathematica 9, new computer... :)

Comment: @cormullion I am not aware of any keyboard that outperforms the Model M for typing feel or durability.  If I can't fix mine I'll buy another.  Besides, have you seen my avatar?  New things confuse old people!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I share your feelings here... why must it be so difficult to find a decent keyboard these days? Since I couldn't bring myself to spend $300 on this I've been making do with substandard ones for a long time now. Computer cases are another thing that seems to have declined in quality over the years.

Comment: @Oleksandr For what it's worth you should be able to get a Model M in very good condition for a lot less than \$300 (I think I saw some for about \$75 last I looked), and if for some reason you just cannot live without a Windows key you can get [Das Keyboard](http://www.daskeyboard.com) for about $120.  I have not gotten a replacement Model M only because I want to get *my* '89 keyboard working again.

Comment: Holy shit! I think I just found out the origins of your penchant for terseness — you just want to minimize the clickety-clicks from your model M!! :D

Comment: @rm-rf lol -- damn it, I literally choked. :^)

Answer (score 4):

Another variation is to use `SplitBy` and `Partition` to separate the list into sublists like so:

```
a = {0, "", 0, 1, 3, 93345, 27, 763212, 3};
splits = Partition[SplitBy[a, TrueQ[# > 9999] &], 2, 2, {1, 1}, {{0}}]
```

> ```
> {{{0, "", 0, 1, 3}, {93345}}, {{27}, {763212}}, {{3}, {0}}}
> ```

Then process the sublists to get the desired result:

```
Flatten[Join[Most[#1], Last[#1] + #2/10.^IntegerLength[#2]] & @@@ splits]
```

> ```
> {0, "", 0, 1, 3.93345, 27.7632, 3}
> ```

I think this should be quite efficient as it keeps the pattern matching to a minimum.

Answer (score 1):

I think @J. M. is right. You should import your data in another way. Try something like:

`StringSplit[StringReplace[Import["C:/Filepath/Filename.txt","List" ],"," -> "." ]]`

If it does not work, it would be nice if you could give us (a part of) your file you want to import.