# Deleting sublists from lists

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I have a list consisting of symbols and integers.  I would like to delete the integers from the list only if a symbol precedes and follows each integer:

```
testList={a,b,3,c,4,5,d,e,f,1,g,4}
```

becomes:

```
resultList={a,b,c,4,5,d,e,f,g,4}
```

This is really a basic question and I almost didn't post it for that reason.

```
testList//.{a__,_Integer,b__}:>{a,b}
```

gets rid of all the integers, not the desired result.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try

```
testList //. {a___, aa_Symbol, _Integer, bb_Symbol, b___} :> {a, aa, bb, b}
```

> ```
> {a, b, c, 4, 5, d, e, f, g, 4}
> ```

```
% == resultList
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Note that I replaced `__` (BlankSequence) with `___` (BlankNullSequence), so this will work for an integer which appears as the second element in the list.

Comment: Yes, I needed the triple underscore.  Thanks!

Comment: You have my vote but FYI there is a better way to approach this style of replacement; please see my complementary answer.

Answer (score 22):

[`ReplaceRepeated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceRepeated.html) is fine for short lists but it will get *very slow* if the list is long, because it starts over from the beginning of the list after each replacement.  A better approach is to start the next replacement *after* the point of the previous one.  One implementation of that:

```
fn1 = # /.
      {a___, aa_Symbol, _Integer, bb_Symbol, b___} :> 
        Join[{a, aa}, fn1 @ {bb, b}] &;
```

With [jjc385](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/11035/jjc385)'s original as:

```
jjc = # //. {a___, aa_Symbol, _Integer, bb_Symbol, b___} :> {a, aa, bb, b} &;
```

Because my function is recursive I will need to raise [`$RecursionLimit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$RecursionLimit.html) for this benchmark.

```
$RecursionLimit = 1*^4;
big = RandomChoice[{1, 2, a, b, c, d}, 10000];

AbsoluteTiming[r1 = jjc[big];]
AbsoluteTiming[r2 = fn1[big];]

r1 === r2
```

> ```
> {60.2394, Null}
>
> {0.328343, Null}
>
> True
> ```

Another example of this method:

- [Replace "," in a list with "."](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23999/121#24002)

A different method that might be of interest is [`SequencePosition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequencePosition.html), though it proves to be slower than `fn1`:

```
fn2 =
  Delete[#, 
    SequencePosition[big, {_Symbol, _Integer, _Symbol}][[All, {1}]] + 1] &;

AbsoluteTiming[r3 = fn2[big];]

r1 === r3
```

> ```
> {1.35279, Null}
>
> True
> ```

---

### Performance Race

jjc385 challenged back with a method an order of magnitude faster than my own `fn1` proposal.  In reply, for the sake of performance tuning I shall make an assumption: that the list is entirely composed of Symbol and Integer expressions.

```
fn3 =
  Pick[
    #, 
    Unitize @ Subtract[ListCorrelate[{4, 2, 1}, Boole[IntegerQ /@ #], 2, 1], 2],
    1
  ] &;
```

Test:

```
big = RandomChoice[{1, 2, a, b, c, d}, 50000];

jjc2[big]; // RepeatedTiming
fn3[big];  // RepeatedTiming

fn3[big] === jjc2[big]
```

> ```
> {0.112, Null}
>
> {0.0153, Null}
>
> True
> ```

Comment: You inspired me to improve, and somehow I beat you by an order of magnitude!  (See my new answer.)  This is at least the second time you've suggested an improvement on one of my `ReplaceRepeated` answers, and I greatly appreciate the comments.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Your second solution is excellent. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 20):

Mr.Wizard inspired me to improve.  While his recursive approach is elegant, the problem clearly can be done linearly.  Indeed:

```
jjc2 = (
   Sow@First@#;
   BlockMap[ 
      If[ ! MatchQ[#, {_Symbol, _Integer, _Symbol}], Sow@#[[2]] ]; &,
      #, 3, 1 ];
   Sow@Last@big;
     // Reap 
    // Last@*Last
  ) &

(r1=jjc2@big); // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.102811, Null}

Mr.Wizard's faster answer:

```
fn1 = # /.
      {a___, aa_Symbol, _Integer, bb_Symbol, b___} :> 
        Join[{a, aa}, fn1 @ {bb, b}] &;

Block[{$RecursionLimit = 1*^4}, (r2=fn1@big);] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {1.26777, Null}

```
r1 === r2
```

> ```
> True
> ```

An order of magnitude?  I'll take it!  :)

Comment: Heh.  Nicely done.  If I have time I'll try to beat *this*. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I'm counting on it!

Comment: Posted as an addendum to my answer.  Please have a look.

Answer (score 16):

The slowest part of @MrWizard's solution is the conversion to 1s and 0s. Here is a faster way to do this conversion:

```
Boole[IntegerQ /@ big]; //RepeatedTiming
Replace[big, {_Integer->1, _->0}, {1}]; //RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.018, Null}
>
> {0.0051, Null}

Here is a slightly different approach to converting the 0|1 list to the desired output:

```
deleteSingletons[list_] := With[{boole = Replace[list, {_Integer->1, _->0}, {1}]},
    Pick[list, Ramp @ ListCorrelate[{-1, 1, -1}, boole, 2, 1], 0]
]
```

And a speed comparison:

```
r1 = fn3[big]; //RepeatedTiming
r2 = deleteSingletons[big]; //RepeatedTiming

r1 === r2
```

> {0.020, Null}
>
> {0.0070, Null}
>
> True

Comment: Nice; I noticed that was the bottleneck in my code and intended to come back to it, but I see you already did.  I wish there were optimized functions that returned a binary value rather than `True` and `False` since the latter cannot be packed.

Answer (score 15):

```
f0 = Flatten @ DeleteCases[{_Integer}] @ SplitBy[#, IntegerQ] &;

f0 @ testList
```

> {a, b, c, 4, 5, d, e, f, g}

Timings between those of Mr.Wizard's `fn3` and jjc385's `jjc2`:

```
i=1;
{#, First@RepeatedTiming[result[i++] = #2[big];]}&@@@ 
 Transpose[{{"jjc2","f0", "fn3"}, {jjc2, f0, fn3}}] // Grid // TeXForm
```

> $\begin{array}{cc}
>  \text{jjc2} & 0.027 \\
>  \text{f0} & 0.012 \\
>  \text{fn3} & 0.0045 \\
> \end{array}$

```
Equal @@ (result /@ {1, 2, 3})
```

> True

Comment: Fast, but simple enough to use in real life.  Big +1

Comment: Yeah, I wish I had been sharp enough to see this equivalent; it's very nice.  Aside: I wish `SplitBy` had an operator form; I wonder why it does not.

Comment: Thank you @Mr.Wizard. Re operator form for `SplitBy`, my first attempt was actually  `Composition[Flatten, DeleteCases[{_Integer}], SplitBy[IntegerQ]]`:)

Answer (score 12):

Another fast one:

```
fsw[x_] := Module[{r = Range@Length@x, i},
  i = Pick[r, x, _Integer];
  x[[Complement[r, Complement[i, i + 1, i - 1, r[[{1, -1}]]]]]]]
```

Comment: This one really nails down... You should also add timings for comparison...

Answer (score 10):

Using a less drastic pattern tend to speed things up a bit, but not as much as `jjc2`

```
fn2 = Delete[#, Transpose[{Pick[Most[#], Differences[#], 2] + 1 &[
                 Position[#, _Symbol, Heads -> False][[All, 1]]]}]] &;
AbsoluteTiming[r2 = fn1[big];]
AbsoluteTiming[r3 = fn2[big];]
AbsoluteTiming[r4 = jjc2[big];]
r3 === r2 === r4
```

> {1.0232561, Null}
>   {0.13014199, Null}
>   {0.085108557, Null}
>   True

Answer (score 4):

Not a candidate in the speed category, but readable.

```
list = {a, b, 3, c, 4, 5, d, e, f, 1, g, 4};
SequenceReplace[list, {a_Symbol, n_Integer, b_Symbol} :> 
  Sequence @@ {a, b}]
```

> {a, b, c, 4, 5, d, e, f, g, 4}

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {a, b, 3, c, 4, 5, d, e, f, 1, g, 4};

Delete[
 list,
 Cases[
  Partition[MapIndexed[{##} &] @ list, 3, 1],
  {{_Symbol, _}, {_Integer, x_}, {_Symbol, _}} :> x]]
```

{a, b, c, 4, 5, d, e, f, g, 4}

Answer (score 1):

Using `SequenceCases` and `DeleteElements`:

```
lst = {a, b, 3, c, 4, 5, d, e, f, 1, g, 4};
res = {a, b, c, 4, 5, d, e, f, g, 4};
DeleteElements[lst, SequenceCases[lst, {a_Symbol, b_Integer, c__Symbol} :> b]] === res

(*True*)
```